# Каков алгоритм составления логической формулы при двух и более выходных сигналах?

Tags: алгоритм

Вопрос из области Компьютерной схемотехники.

Не могу найти примеры, как составлять формулу на логических элементах, если дана такая таблица истинности, в которой два или более выходных сигнала.

Например, таблица истинности для двух входных сигналов a b и двух выходных сигналов V1 V2

```
a b V1 V2
0 0 0  0
0 1 1  0
1 0 1  0
1 1 0  1
```

Как составляется формула если имеется один выходной сигнал **понятно**

```
a b c V
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 *
0 1 0 1 *
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1 *
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
```

Согласно СДНФ (Совершенная дизъюнктивная нормальная формула) для показанной выше таблицы истинности с одним выходным сигналом V, формула будет следующая:

`f(a, b, c) = (!a) & (!b) & c ) | ( (!a) & b & (!c) ) | (a & (!b) & (!c)),`

где `!a` - инверсия бита `a`,

`&` операция логического "И",

`|` операция логического "ИЛИ".

Каков алгоритм составления формулы при двух и более выходных сигналах?

Comment: Просто идея: а если рассматривать каждый выходной сигнал отдельно? Т.е. для каждого выхода будет своя формула

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, кажется начинаю понимать, получается, что будет два независимых блока элементов, описанный каждый формулой для своего выходного сигнала и входные сигналы будут подаваться в оба полученных блока.

Comment: `V1 = (a & !b) | (!a & b)` , `V2 = a & b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть один метод если хотите получить несколько значений в одной формуле

по задаче V1 и V2 равны

```
V1 = (a & !b) | (!a & b)
V2 = a & b
```

вы хотите что бы эти значении были в одном числе. Можно создать `V = (V1)(V2)` по битам

```
V = ((a & !b) | (!a & b) << 1) | (a & b)
```

`V` будет иметь 4 значения. `0, 1, 2, 3`  или `00, 01, 10, 11` соотвественно

когда вам понадобится значения `V1` или `V2` вы можете получить из `V`

```
V1 = (V >> 1) & 1
V2 = V & 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Многие вещи можно делать просто арифметикой.
Например, при `n= 4a + 2b + c` вышеприведённую СДНФ `V` для трёх сигналов можно вычислять по тривиальной формуле `V = (n==1) || (n==2) || ($n==4)`.

Это позволит сначала расправиться со случаем нескольких сигналов на входе, а потом продублировать технологию на каждый выходной сигнал.